# PHP Threads Sharing a Central Socket Object

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I am building a multi-threaded PHP CLI application that speaks with a server via sockets. The intention is for the application to only create one connection with the server (via a separate class) and then allow the child threads to use the established socket object. The following code fails:

```
<?php

/**
 * Test child class
 **/
class test extends Thread {

    private $server;

    public function __construct( &$server ) {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    public function run() {
        echo $this->server->request( 'INFO 1-10' );
    }

}


/**
 * Socket class
 **/
class socket {

    private $socket;

    public function __construct( $host, $port ) {
        $this->socket = fsockopen( $host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10 );
    }

    public function request( $out ) {
        fwrite( $this->socket, $out . "\r\n" );
        return fgets( $this->socket );
    }

}


/**
 * main class
 **/
class main {

    private $server;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->server = new socket( '192.168.1.141', 5250 );
    }

    public function main() {
        $test = new test( $this->server );
        $test->start();
    }

}

$main = new main();
$main->main();

?>
```

The error message is:

```
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /test_stackoverflow/test.sh on line 35
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /test_stackoverflow/test.sh:0
PHP   2. socket->request() /test_stackoverflow/test.sh:17
PHP   3. fwrite() /test_stackoverflow/test.sh:35
PHP Warning:  fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in /test_stackoverflow/test.sh on line 36
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /test_stackoverflow/test.sh:0
PHP   2. socket->request() /test_stackoverflow/test.sh:17
PHP   3. fgets() /test_stackoverflow/test.sh:36
```

If I remove the Thread aspect, and use the following code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Test child class
 **/
class test {

    private $server;

    public function __construct( &$server ) {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    public function run() {
        echo $this->server->request( 'INFO 1-10' );
    }

}


/**
 * Socket class
 **/
class socket {

    private $socket;

    public function __construct( $host, $port ) {
        $this->socket = fsockopen( $host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10 );
    }

    public function request( $out ) {
        fwrite( $this->socket, $out . "\r\n" );
        return fgets( $this->socket );
    }

}


/**
 * main class
 **/
class main {

    private $server;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->server = new socket( '192.168.1.141', 5250 );
    }

    public function main() {
        $test = new test( $this->server );
        $test->run();
    }

}

$main = new main();
$main->main();

?>
```

This code runs successfully.

It appears that passing the $server object (socket class) by reference to a class that extends Thread causes the issue.

I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish my original goal of building a multi-threaded PHP CLI application that speaks with a server via a single sockets connection.

Thanks for your assistance!

*The final application will be much more robust, allowing threads to be spawned dynamically. The example I provided above is to display the root issue, and nothing else.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the socket class declaration to extend the [Threaded class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.threaded.php), and now it works fine.

```
<?php

/**
 * Test child class
 **/
class test extends Threaded {

    private $server;

    public function __construct( &$server ) {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    public function run() {
        echo $this->server->request( 'INFO 1-10' );
    }

}


/**
 * Socket class
 **/
class socket extends Threaded {

    private $socket;

    public function __construct( $host, $port ) {
        $this->socket = fsockopen( $host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10 );
    }

    public function request( $out ) {
        fwrite( $this->socket, $out . "\r\n" );
        return fgets( $this->socket );
    }

}


/**
 * main class
 **/
class main {

    private $server;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->server = new socket( '192.168.1.141', 5250 );
    }

    public function main() {
        $test = new test( $this->server );
        $test->run();
    }

}

$main = new main();
$main->main();

?>
```